# Role of the Yukawa potential

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, potential-energy, strong-force

What is the [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) converging to zero? Afaik the strong potential rises with the distance between quarks, hence, it should rise accordingly.

[image: pot]

Comment: To be honest, most of your questions can be answered by slowly reading the linked Wikipedia article. But also if you search on PhysicsSE, you'll find many Q&A's: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326260/127780, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/467728/127780, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9663/127780, ...

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the question v3.

The Yukawa interaction was usually thought to describe nucleon-nucleon interactions (nucleon = proton or neutron). Nowadays, one *cannot* view it as a fundamental model for quarks and gluons.

In order to derive the Yukawa potential, you need to consider massive spin-1 bosons (Yukawa initially thought of pions mediating the strong force between nucleons), as indicated in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326260/127780).

Finally, yes, the strong potential between quarks and gluons is (assumed to be) linearly increasing, but this has nothing to do with the Yukawa potential between nucleons.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/498136/is-the-strong-potential-repulsive-for-high-distances