# Is the strong potential repulsive for high distances?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, potential-energy

The negative region in a potential is attractive and the positive region is repulsive. At least in case of the coulomb potential:

[image: eCoulomb]

When having a look at the strong potential it is obvious that the potential is rising linearly. Does it mean it is repulsive from about 0.5 fm?

[image: strong potential[1]]

Comment: Small comment: the value $0.5$ fm depends on how you choose $\alpha_s$ and $k$. Those values are not at all set in stone.

Comment: The top figure gives you a couple of hints. Note the label on the vertical axis; "tot" stands for total, meaning several effect added together. And the falling slope is attributed to "coulomb" meaning the electrostatic contribution.

Comment: *The negative region in a potential is attractive and the positive region is repulsive.* NO! The sign of the potential is irrelevant. Only the sign of its *slope* matters. Do you see how the particle “rolls down the potential hill”?

Comment: I thought the same as the coulomb potential has its barrier in a positive region where it still is attractive. So it is attractive, when the slope is positive?

Comment: *So it is attractive, when the slope is positive?* Yes, a force is attractive when the slope of its potential is positive. *I thought the same as the coulomb potential has its barrier in a positive region where it still is attractive.* I can’t figure out what you mean, but you seem to be confused.

Comment: The repulsive $1/r$ Coulomb potential between same-sign charges has negative slope everywhere. The attractive $-1/r$ Coulomb potential between opposite-sign charges has positive slope everywhere. Neither changes its sign or its slope.

Comment: The potential barrier in the upper graph for nuclei comes from combining repulsive Coulomb force between protons with attractive nuclear force between nucleons.

Comment: The lower graph is for force between two quarks.